# GPIO communication with javascript with Jetson nano

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, gpio, nvidia-jetson

I want to connect some push buttons to the gpio of my jetson nano for communicating with a javascript electron.js application.

There is the [NVIDIA jetson-gpio python library](https://pypi.org/project/Jetson.GPIO) but I have without success trying to find a javascript equivalent for communicating with the gpio through node.js ...

A workaround would be to handle the input from gpio with python and then setup communication from python to javascript through websockets but a library for communicating directly with the gpio would be more straightforward ...

Anyone with a suggestion for possible solution for handle this?